# I don`t understand why it adds another 0 in my output. I input 100 and 20 and got 100 and 200 , what can i do?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add (int num1, int num2)
{
  cout << num1 << " " << num2;

  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  int num1, num2;
  cin >> num1;
  cin >> num2;

  cout << add (num1, num2);
}
```

I tried printing two numbers form input and it doesn`t work. i expectet to print the numbers entered but it adds a 0 to the second number.

Comment: the `0` added is the result of the `add` function which you do print to `std::cout`...

Comment: Voted to reopen. This problem was **not** caused by typos. It was caused by misunderstanding what the code did. If you or I wrote it, sure, it would be a typo. But for beginners it isn't. Don't judge beginners by the standards of experienced programmers.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the two numbers inside your function `add` and then in `main()` you are printing the return value of `add()` which is `0` - i.e. `return 0;`

Change `cout << add (num1, num2);` to `add (num1, num2);`

or more realistically:

```
int add (int num1, int num2)
{
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

if you actually want to add the numbers and return the result

Comment: I assume, He wants to print the sum of the numbers.